# knuminput.h not available in QT Creator

Tags: qt, qt-creator, fedora, kde-plasma

I am using QT Creator on Fedora 28.

My GUI contains "KIntNumInput" objects. The compiler throws an error in `ui_mainwindow.h` (an automatically generated file that is not part of my project and cannot be edited):

`knuminput.h: No such file or directory`.

What do I have to install to be able to use this class?

Are there any alternatives in case it's not possible?

Edit: The file /usr/include/KF5/KDELibs4Support/knuminput.h exists, the compiler just doesn't find it

Comment: In SO you should not add SOLVED, the correct thing is to publish an answer and mark it as correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution: Added the include path `/usr/include/KF5/KDELibs4Support/` to my project's configuration (`.pro`) file

```
INCLUDEPATH += /usr/include/KF5/KDELibs4Support
```

Turns out this class is deprecated anyways and the Qt-equivalent (QSpinBox) which I, thanks to its not obvious name didn't find, should be used instead.

Answer (score 0):

you are missing the kdelibs and therefore all the headers that QT needs to compile the code....

install then by doing:

```
Update the package index:
$ dnf -y update

Install libkf5kdelibs4support-dev deb package:
$ dnf install kf5-kdelibs4support-devel
```

refer to this

https://fedora.pkgs.org/26/fedora-x86_64/kf5-kdelibs4support-devel-5.35.0-1.fc26.x86_64.rpm.html

if any further info about the kf5-kdelibs4support-devel package in fedora
....

Comment: That's what I thought too, but installing that package doesn't solve the problem.

Edit: I know the file is at the correct location in the file system (/usr/include/KF5/KDELibs4Support/knuminput.h), the compiler just doesn't find it.
The #include command has just the filename, not the path.